XCode Errors on 16.0 Upgrade with azure-notificationhubs-ios v3.1.5
I recently upgraded XCode to 16 and I am trying to run my project but am getting multiple errors (8) which seem to be related to three missing files:

'SBTemplateRegistration.h' file not found
'ANHAsync.h' file not found
'ANHApplicationProvider.h' file not found

All are related to Microsoft Azure Notification Hubs SDK for Apple. I am on version 3.1.5. Here are the 8 errors:

SBLocalStorage - 'SBTemplateRegistration.h' file not found
SBNotificationHubHelper - 'SBTemplateRegistration.h' file not found
SBRegistrationParser - 'SBTemplateRegistration.h' file not found
SBURLConnection - 'ANHAsync.h' file not found
ANHHttpCall - 'ANHAsync.h' file not found
ANHNotificationHubAppDelegateForwarder - 'ANHAsync.h' file not found
ANHUserNotificationCenterDelegeForwarder - 'ANHAsync.h' file not found
MSNotificationHub - 'ANHApplicationProvider.h' file not found

Has anybody else been getting this error?

I had a similar issue and haven't been able to find anything. I was able to work around it by downgrading to Xcode version 15.4, though that's a bit of a brute-force solution.

As a note for anyone looking at this: this isn't possible if you've already upgraded your Mac as 15.4 isn't compatible with Sequoia:( and a MacOS downgrade isn't possible without having to backup and reinstall all your files. Hoping they come out with a fix soon

There is a discussion going on in the issues section for the SPM library
https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-ios/issues/153
Possible solution is

download the  WindowsAzureMessaging-SDK-Apple-XCFramework-3.1.5.zip file from https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-ios/releases

Remove the SPM dependency of existing WindowsAzureMessaging package

Uzip the file downloaded in step 1

Drag and drop the WindowsAzureMessaging.xcframework folder under the Frameworks folder. 


5. Rebuild your project you should have a successful build.
